# My android notification icon is a white square

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I am using Raix:Push (Meteor.js push-notification plugin) to send notifications to my android app (Built using meteor's inbuilt cordova). The only problem is that I am getting a white square as notification Icon when the notification arrives. I read we have to use a white notification with a transparent background added to the following path while building the app.

```
cordova-build-override/platforms/android/res/drawable/pushicon.png
```

I have done this but nothing seems to have changed. I still get a white square. I have also added the name of the icon to the client startup file under Push.Configure

Anyone experienced this before, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I needed to put this folder structure:

```
cordova-build-override/platforms/android/res/drawable/pushicon.png
```

at the root of my project, as opposed to inside the /.meteor folder

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the icon in your push client?

```
 Push.Configure({
android: {
  senderID: Meteor.settings.public.fcm.senderId,
  iconColor: '#0C431B',
  icon: 'pushicon',
  badge: true,
  sound: true,
  alert: true,
  vibrate: true,
},
```